# How to generate a 16 digit unique number for each call by a service deployed on multiple servers without database?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, cloud

I have a Java service that generates a 16 digit unique number using current time in the format yymmddhhmmssmsms. And it handles multiple calls on the same mili-second using Atomic Long.
But now the problem is that I need this service on multiple cloud machines. How can I handle calls at the same microsecond on different servers and generate a unique number for each of this calls.
And I dont want to use database for this.

EDIT:
I understand UUID can be a solution. But UUID generates a random no. everytime, not unique, though the chances of collision are very low.

Comment: Use a random UUID.

Comment: Can't use UUID.2 reasons.
1. Its alpha numeric
2. It's random, not necessarily unique for every call. Time is going to be unique.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Either you use a UUID or you centralize the unique number generator (whether you do that with a database or some other way, the number still needs to come from a single source).

Comment: UUID is virtually unique. The chance of it generating the same number twice is vanishingly small. Research it. And a UUID is basically a string of bits. You can interpret it as a number.

Comment: Just append the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

A think, you can try to use UUID.randomUUID() object

Answer (score 0):

The UUID v4 is the right choice for distributed systems.

> The UUID v4 implementation uses random numbers as the source. The Java
> implementation is SecureRandom – which uses an unpredictable value as
> the seed to generate random numbers to reduce the chance of
> collisions.
> Source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid
>
> Secure Random: This class provides a cryptographically strong random number generator (RNG). Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Example how to use the UUID:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a random number alone (such as a random UUID) should only be done if—

- you have a way to check the number for uniqueness across all calls, or
- you can tolerate the risk of generating the same number for different calls.

If you find it appropriate, try assigning each server a unique number (e.g., by requesting a unique number from a central database). Then each server can generate a unique ID for each call it makes by appending a random number to that unique number; this may work well because the server can now more easily check the IDs it then generates for uniqueness, as no further contact with a central database or other servers is required.

See also my section on [generating unique random identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers).